# Unable to write to SQL Server using C#; no errors produced yet nothing is written to table

Tags: c#, sql-server

After several hours of researching and not finding a solution, I am now requesting assistance. I am not a C# wizard; your knowledge and insight on this will be greatly appreciated. My goal is to write an access attempt to an audit log on each page load.

1. I have verified the connection string's Server\Instance, Database, User, and Password
2. I have done a linked server test from another server using the credentials copy/pasted from the connection string, with success.
3. I have validated the query in SSMS.
4. SQL Server Profiler does not even register an attempt to connect to the database

My code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public string string1 = "";
        public string string2 = "";
        public string string3 = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(1,5);
            string2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToLower();
            string3 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

            // Define SQL connection string and query
            string connString =
                "Server=SERVER\\INSTANCE;" +
                "Database=DB;" +
                "User Id=USER;" +
                "Password=PSWD;";

            string queryString =
                "insert into dbo.TABLE ([col1], [col2], [col3])" +
                "values (@val1, @val2, @val3)";

            // Write to DB
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = string1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = string2;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = string3;

                    conn.Open();
                }

                //conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to execute the query.

Comment: You're creating the connection, opening it, creating the command .... but you never actually **EXECUTE** that command! No wonder you don't see anything in SQL Server Profiler - there's nothing to see! After the `conn.Open();`, you need to have a `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to actually send the command to SQL Server and have it run ....

Comment: I realise you are just beginning in C# land, but hand-crafting SQL is really not a good think to think in C#.  Technologies like Linq and packages like EntityFramework abstract away all the hard things like making creating SQL, making connections/commands etc.   It would also have probably prevented you from making this error too.  Just sayin.

Comment: If you don't execute the code, how do you expect it to be in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing the query.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr)){
conn.open();
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn)){
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", string1);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", string2);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", string3);

      cmd.ExeucuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), particularly in relation to strings.

Comment: @Voxum Well that certainly does help! Rookie mistake.

Comment: @LarsTech I also came across an article that I should not use AddWithValue, as it invokes implicit conversion. Do I understand that concern correctly? I have converted to Parameters.Add().

Comment: @Bryan__T: it might incur implicit conversions - and some times, the *guessing* of what datatype a parameter is can be totally off and cause all sorts of trouble. Avoid it if ever possible - there are much better alternatives

Comment: Didn't know of the implicit conversion with AddWithValue. I'll keep an eye out for that in the future!